# Set ASP.NET Page Culture from <html lang="fr"> tag?

Tags: asp.net, html, localization, globalization

Can I have my ASP.NET pages set their Culture & UICulture from the `<html lang="fr">` tag / attribute?

I'm looking for a solution with the least code impact that would be suitable for web site authoring with only a little code behind.

Note, I've looked at numerous posts on ASP.NET Page culture, but none of them refer to picking up the setting from the `<html>` tag and applying it to the ASP.NET Page class.

Comment: Why do you wan't that? Why don't you use globalization inside web.config?

Comment: And by the way, globalization can also be set at runtime.

Comment: I want to do this because the page authors work strictly with the HTML in the aspx markup and use the `<html>` tag to indicate the page language. It will be easier to not have to train them in ASP.NET Page directive etc. But I am tasked with adding additional dynamic content in the code behind that is language sensitive.

Answer (score 5):

You can set Culture and UICulture attributes of the @ Page directive:

```
<%@ Page UICulture="es" Culture="es-MX" %>
```

as you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks I'm aware of that, but it doesn't address my question. I want the ASP.NET values determined by and set from the HTML markup lang attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add:

```
runat="server" id="HtmlMasterTag"
```

to the html tag, you can do something of this kind in the code behind of the page (or in the one of a common base page):

```
string language = HtmlMasterTag.Attributes["lang"];
```

and use the variable *language* to set UICulture and Culture

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. The Page Culture and UICulture must be set in an override of the Page InitializeCulture method. This method is called during the Start stage of the page life-cycle. The server controls including <html runat="server"> are not available until the Initialization stage which comes after the Start stage. I tested it in code. Refer to [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).